# What is the meaning of the expression "...where rules are a convenience"?

Tags: expressions

I encountered the phrase

"Paida fun is free-wheeling player fun, **where rules are a convenience**."

in the context of roleplaying games. 
As a native German speaker, I am uncertain of the meaning of the phrase, am I correct to guess:

"Paida fun is free-wheeling player fun, **where rules are not so important, but simply used beacause it is easier to use rules than not to have rules at all**."

Comment: I suspect convenience may be a poor translation. Given [a first look at what Paida purports to be](http://bbc.com/news/world-asia-china-32545591), I'd say it is probably closer to necessity (Notwendigkeit) than it is to convenience (Nútzlichkeit)

Comment: Is this the source of your sentence? http://triplecrit.com/gamemastering-for-emotional-impact-pt-2/ The rest of that paragraph seems to explain it pretty well. *"Players looking to get some Paidial fun would prefer winging the rules-calls, going for whatever feels right at the moment."*

Answer (score -1):

It is a pun intended to add 'fun.'

And, you guessed it correctly!

*...'where rules are a convenience.'*  means rules are just for fun and **not to bother you.** They are convenient!

Another such sentence I remember is: *There's only one rule that there is no rule!*